# Fortran shared library for Python with use of OpenMP and Intel compilers

Tags: python, fortran, openmp, intel, ctypes

I have a problem while making a shared library in Fortran to be loaded from Python. I've put together a minimal example to show the problem:

The subroutine:

```
subroutine sgesvf() bind(C, name="sgesvf")

implicit none

real*4 a(4,4), b(4), c(4,4)
integer pivs(4), inf, n, i, j

! Externals from the LAPACK library
external sgesv

!     Initialize the matrix a and the vector b
data a/ 1, 2, 3, 4, &
   6, 7, 9, 9, &
   11,12,19,14, &
   16,17,18,12/
data b/ 1, 3, 5, 6/

n=4
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(NONE) &
!$OMP SHARED(A,C,N) &
!$OMP PRIVATE(I,J) &
!$OMP SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,1)
do i = 2, n
  do j = 1, i
     c(j,i) = ( a(j,i) + a(j,i-1) ) / 2.0
  end do
end do

!     Compute the solution
call sgesv(4, 1, a, 4, pivs, b, 4, inf)

!     Figure out if sgesv found a solution or not
if (inf .eq. 0) then
   write (*,*) 'successful solution'
else if (inf .lt. 0) then
   write (*,*) 'illegal value at: %d', -inf
   stop
else if (inf .gt. 0) then
   write (*,*) 'matrix was singular'
   stop
else
   write (*,*) 'unknown result (can''t happen!)'
   stop
end if

write(*,*) 'pivs=', pivs

end subroutine sgesvf
```

which tests the most important tools I use in my real code, that is OpenMP and Lapack/Blas.

If I compile ignoring the OpenMP directives, that is:

```
ifort -O2 -warn all -fPIC -I/opt/intel/mkl/include -module Release/ -c main.f90 -o Release/main.o
ifort -shared  Release/main.o -o Release/libshared_lib_for_python_example.so -L/opt/intel/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt -lpthread -lm
```

and use as:

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libshared_lib_for_python_example.so')
print lib.sgesvf()
```

I get:

```
successful solution
pivs=           4           4           3           4           0
```

If I include the OpenMP:

```
ifort -O2 -warn all -fPIC -openmp -I/opt/intel/mkl/include -module Release/ -c main.f90 -o Release/main.o
ifort -shared  Release/main.o -o Release/libshared_lib_for_python_example.so -L/opt/intel/lib/intel64 -openmp -lmkl_rt -lpthread -lm
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libshared_lib_for_python_example.so')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64/libifcoremt.so.5: undefined symbol: _intel_fast_memmove
```

I've tried several variations I found on forums (like adding -lifport -lifcoremt -lifcore -lsvml -lirc to the linking, make sure I'm linking with the right libraries, etc.). I've also tried posting on Intel forum since 2 weeks without any result.

I work under Debian Linux 7.0. My Intel compiler is: Version 14.0.2.144 Build 20140120.

Cross-posted on: http://software.intel.com/forums/topic/506517

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting an RPATH on your shared lib?

Comment: Works for me on CentOS 6.2 with ifort 13.0.1.

Comment: As soon as I posted this, I think I have the solution. If I link with the static libraries the problem is solved:

"-Wl,--start-group  /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a /opt/intel/lib/intel64/libirc.a /opt/intel/lib/intel64/libimf.a -Wl,--end-group -L/opt/intel/lib/intel64 -liomp5 -lpthread -lm"

libirc and libimf were needed, otherwise I was getting an error "undefined symbol: _intel_fast_memmove"

Comment: @Andrey Sobolev It worked "as-is"? Haven't tried with that compiler. Maybe my path is not set correctly?

Comment: Yes, it worked as-is, with shared linking. Haven't checked though if omp threads are spawned.

Comment: Check if it gets sped up!

Comment: You are probably looking for the -static-intel flag to the compiler http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/464300

Comment: Don't you need !$OMP END statements, by the way?

Comment: By the way: You might consider using f2py instead of ctypes for calling fortran from python. It makes is very simple to pass numpy arrays between the two, and the resulting module can be imported as a normal python module.

Comment: @amaurea If you use parallel loop and not simply parallel, the END statement is optional. f2py is good but for small cases. The real program has around 50 files with 1-2k lines each. Uses modules, interaces, etc. I don't think f2py can handle it. At least not easily.